# What exactly are bases vectors

Tags: linear-algebra, vector-spaces, vectors, linear-transformations

I have watched 3 blue one brown Essence of Linear Algebra tutorials [enter link description here](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=kYB8IZa5AuE&index=3&list=PLZHQObOWTQDPD3MizzM2xVFitgF8hE_ab). I want to ask one question. Let suppose we have a 3x4 transformation matrix as follows

A =

```
7    3    -9    8

6    2    -8    7

8    4     0    7
```

The basis of vector A are

```
{ (7,3,-9,8), (6, 2, -8, 7), (8, 4, 0, 7) }
```

And here is the vector which is to be transformed

B =

```
1    2     4    5
```

When we will multiply the matrix with vector it will take it from R4 --> R3. 
as

```
17   13    51
```

Please tell me, when we write the multiplication in terms of linear combination it is like that.

```
1 [ 7    6    8 ]  + 2 [ 3    2     4] + 4 [ -9   8    0 ] + 5 [ 8   7    7]
```

But as the video of 3blue one brown suggested for R2 --> R2 transformation.

```
a( transformed vector i ) +  b (transormed vector j) for vector to be transformed [a, b]
```

But in the case defined above it is streching its coloumns which are not vectors.

Please tell me the solution of this, or any wrong concept I have.
Thanks

Comment: When we talk about a basis, it is with respect to a vector space. $A$ is not a vector space here. Rather, the rows of $A$ form a basis for a subspace of $\mathbb{R}^4.$

Comment: Okay, yes we have 3 vectors from R4 which span R3. But my question is How exactly [ 1 2 4 5 ] are stretching the vectors of A to reach R3. In this case it is stretching in this way 1 [ 7    6    8 ]  + 2 [ 3    2     4] + 4 [ -9   8    0 ] + 5 [ 8   7    7].  But  [ 7   6  8] is not a vector

Comment: No. They do not span $\mathbb{R}^3.$

Answer (score 1):

The columns of the matrix are vectors too, though in this case in $\mathbb R^3$ (not $\mathbb R^4$ like the rows).

It is a fact that the image of a linear transformation is always the span of the $\mathbf{columns}$ of any matrix representing it.

Comment: But how can columns be a vector. They do not have any magnitude or direction ? Please explain me

Comment: Any $n$-tuple can be thought of as a vector.

Comment: @MuhammadRafique The "*definition*" of a vector being something that has magnitude and direction is incorrect.  See a more complete definition of [vector here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Vector_(mathematics_and_physics)).  That being said, $\left[\begin{smallmatrix}7\\6\\8\end{smallmatrix}\right]$ does happen to have magnitude and direction when treated as an element in $\Bbb R^3$ with the standard euclidean bases and metric... It is $7$ units in the $i$ direction, $6$ units in the $j$ direction and $8$ units in the $k$ direction and has magnitude $\sqrt{7^2+6^2+8^2}$

Comment: But what will be its geometric interpretation. Like if we consider the rows of this vector we can understand that they have been created using the linear combination of basis vectors of that space. But how can we explain the origin of the column vectors. It means there will be whole different geometry for row vector and column vectors ?

Comment: @MuhammadRafique read about [row spaces and column spaces](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Row_and_column_spaces), two of the fundamental subspaces related to a matrix.

Comment: @JMoravitz ok, let me see. Thank you